# What is the difference between build id and serial number?

Tags: bios, desktop, serial

My serial number and build ID are completely different. Since my computer has been doing strange things (even after reset) what should I use to identify my desktop (HP) when I call support?
Moreover, is the Build ID the *electronic* serial number? The BIOS utility only gives me the Build ID and not the serial number.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Contact HP and request they tell you what they need and how to get it.